# AWS - What a canonical request is really?

Tags: php, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to work directly with the REST API for the S3 service from Amazon and I don't get to understand what a canonical request is.

What I understand is:

- You need an Authorization header or query string parameters (I will use the header)
- This Authorization header contains a hashed HTTP request (the canonical request)
- This HTTP request needs a hashed payload and then is concatenated to a longer string.
- This string is hashed several times.
- The result is the Authentication header.

[image: Authentication header creation line]

Then, the questions are:

- The canonical request is the same as the real request?
- A canonical request string is made only once and then used on the next requests?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `canonical request` is a just a vocabulary thing.

> The canonical request is the same as the real request?

It is a representation of the real request; per your screenshot, it is defined as

```
CanonicalRequest =
  HTTPRequestMethod + '\n' +
  CanonicalURI + '\n' +
  CanonicalQueryString + '\n' +
  CanonicalHeaders + '\n' +
  SignedHeaders + '\n' +
  HexEncode(Hash(RequestPayload))
```

of course if you pass that strict into your browser, it will not be understood and it will not be executed so it will be transform (make encoding nice etc ...)

so for example you will get a canonical representation of your request defined as

```
CanonicalRequest =
  "GET" + '\n' +
  "http://s3.amazonaws.com/examplebucket" + '\n' +
  URI-encode("marker")+"="+URI-encode("someMarker")+"&"+URI-encode("max-keys")+"="+URI-encode("20") + "&" +URI-encode("prefix")+"="+URI-encode("somePrefix") + '\n' +
  Lowercase("host")+":"+Trim("s3.amazonaws.com")+"\n"+Lowercase("x-amz-<something>")+":"+Trim("<the_value>")+ '\n' +
  "host;x-amz-<something (same as above)>" + '\n' +
  HexEncode(Hash(RequestPayload))
```

Then from this definition, the system will create the "real" request meaning the one that will be executed against the server

Comment: *"Then from this definition, the system will create the "real" request meaning the one that will be executed against the server"*  From this? No, the canonical request is a deterministic representation of the request elements, "canonical" meaning that when S3 receives the request it can re-generate this identical string from the actual request, and calculate the signature you should have sent, to see if you got it right (which proves you are using the secret matching your access key id).  Nothing is derived *from* the canonical request, since it is immediately hashed and discarded in step 2.

Comment: the canonical request has to have the same headers? what about the dates in headers (in canonical and real requests) and dates used during the Authentication header generation? must they be the same?

Comment: how can I generate canonical form programatically?

Comment: where do you find the canonical uri of let's say an api in API Gateway?