# How to debug Amazon reply 'The String-to-Sign should have been' upon Restricted Data Token request?

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to make Amazon Selling Partner API Restricted Data Token request and I am getting error message with explanation:

```
'GET/tokens/2021-03-01/restrictedDataToken
host:sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com
x-amz-access-token:Atza|IwEBIKl_cR0g8tkcs-XR_6aoWu_4kPbRlBnW07MUCQkS5_I3nA716HJxM_A7TIjXb3oUkBMjw7Mqxq1kGsbTnajJvgBT2yisnu6AEuZvtEpSgCIih9S9-0NrnLWQT5IUlWuvzUiXmogfKZghVoT65b3_WWV29mxLyhL1yK61NylCrFQCa5vwzT4m2Tuoo6dIrE77Qf79cRzwpiLbaLP8fiM3XgqMVSiDt246BBYWkI-Rg0t2FatoQHseE0sYp4SPfWY4c-AZEtSFzejVPcQRTsLIgm1SWmwIojO6b-mpAOIW2MMj00Vy7AAs6WzrS2z9PqW2ecrKoH-p7BNnRuIE672ofmEc
x-amz-date:20211201T141644Zhost;
x-amz-access-token;
x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
'The String-to-Sign should have been'
AWS4-HMAC-SHA25620211201T141644Z20211201/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_requestda72cd0eaab649d1219a0316d8a19360f10c2d9bb10fe716bc828fac408d2647'
```

The last 2 lines are causing confusion for me and my question is about them:

```
'The String-to-Sign should have been'
    AWS4-HMAC-SHA25620211201T141644Z20211201/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_requestda72cd0eaab649d1219a0316d8a19360f10c2d9bb10fe716bc828fac408d2647'
```

I am trying to understand the provided `String-to-Sign` and my understanding is that Amazon returns complete mess in this error message. The strange things are:

1. Amazon calls `AWS4-HMAC-SHA25620211201T141644Z20211201/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_requestda72cd0eaab649d1219a0316d8a19360f10c2d9bb10fe716bc828fac408d2647` but it already contains the signature (`da72cd0eaab649d1219a0316d8a19360f10c2d9bb10fe716bc828fac408d2647` in this case);
2. This string is not in the usual format `header-name:value`, e.g. my string-to-sign is very clear structure:

   Authorization=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<PRIVATE_INFORMATION>/20211201/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request,
   SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date, Signature=aaab78223b9f6ba2ce7466bc134b1976dcb28efd0b60c80c688a4f531690dec2
3. Amazon `String-to-sign` does not include credentials/AWSKey, so, it could be made by anyone.
4. Amazon `String-to-sign` does not include the information about signed-headers, apparently Amazon assumes exact format (number and types of headers) in RDT request, strange deviation from the flexibility.

So, my understanding is that the example `String-to-Sign` returned by Amazon is erroneus and not reliable hint which I could use for correcting my service. I have used my `String-to-Sign` in many succesfull Amazon Selling Parnter API requests (that do not require RDT) and Amazon itself is saying (in https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/issues/639):

> Make a request to Tokens API signed with the LWA token (the way a
> normal SP API request is constructed). Add the restricted API path and
> method as part of the request body parameters.

And exactly that I did: I just changed the host name and added the JSON-serialized description of the restricted resources to the body of this request. No change in the signature processes. But Amazon does not accept that.

Answer (score 0):

I have confused in my question the two representations of the my request. Amazon reports the special representation of the request using canonical string of the request and the stringtosign that is calculated from the canonical string.

The picture in the question [AWS - What a canonical request is really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664755/aws-what-a-canonical-request-is-really) is worth thousand words. Amazon first signs the request with the LWA access data that identifies the program/service that is making the request. This signature is just addition of header `x-amz-access-token`. THis header (AWS access token signature) together with the original headers fortms the final request that is made into canonical request (Step 1 in the picture) by ordering the headers, parameters. And then all the remaining steps of the picture is executed.

In my question is read the canonical string and stringtosign from the Amazon response and I have tried to compare those 2 strings with the headers of my request. That, of course, is not directly comparable.

I should have to debug/trace my code and see how my own program computes the canonical string and stringtosign.

If I am using the swagger-generated C# code from the Selling Parnter API documentation, then the code that generated canonical string and stringtosign is in the procedure `AWSSigV4Signer.cs` `procedure public IRestRequest Sign(IRestRequest request, string host)`. AWSSigV4 signing in this case is just adding additional headers to the ultimate request. So - I had to trace into `AWSSigV4Signer.Sign` procedure to get canonical string and stringtosign for comparison with Amazon response.

Of course, finally those pairs of strings are not comparable byte-by-byte, because the canonical string contains x-amz-access-token that is computed by LWS access data and those are program specific and my understanding is that Amazon includes some generic x-amz-access-token data in its response, that is why the exact comparison at the level of complete values is not possible.