# How to add and hash HTTP body to the Amazon Selling Partner API GET request (e.g. Restricted Data Token API)? C# version

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to call Amazon Selling Partner API Token API to get RDT token. I have working program that is making successful GET requests to the Orders API but REST requests to the Orders API contain the headers and URL parameters only. Token API requests contain (additionally) HTTP body as well in which the list of Restricted Resources is saved.

Amazon replys with

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. 
Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.
Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'GET
 /tokens/2021-03-01/restrictedDataToken
 ...
 host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date\n
 e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
 ...
 The String-to-Sign should have been
 ...
 ...
```

in my Token API program. `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855` is the key to my problem. This is Hashed paylod (see the picture in the coming link) that is computers from the initial set of headers, URL parameters and body content. The Hashed payload which is calculated by my program is the same that Amazon returns and accepts for the requests without body. But Amazon's and my program's Hashed payloads are different for the requests with body. So, I have concluded that my program adds and hashes body differently from the Amazon and that is why Amazon is not accepty my Token API requests.

[AWS - What a canonical request is really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664755/aws-what-a-canonical-request-is-really) has nice picture, how the complete request to the Amazon services is computed.

I am computing and adding HTTP body with the C# code:

```
        Model.RestrictedResource restrictedResource = new Model.RestrictedResource(
            Model.RestrictedResource.MethodEnum.GET,
            "/orders/v0/orders",
            new List<String> {"buyerInfo", "shippingAddress"});
        List<Model.RestrictedResource> restrictedResources = new List<Model.RestrictedResource>();
            restrictedResources.Add(restrictedResource);
            Model.CreateRestrictedDataTokenRequest request = new Model.CreateRestrictedDataTokenRequest("", restrictedResources);

            IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(rdt_resource, Method.GET);
            restRequest.AddParameter("MarketplaceIds", marketplace_id, ParameterType.QueryString);
            restRequest.AddJsonBody(Serialize(request));
            //restRequest.AddBody(Serialize(request)); //Alternative solution, the same Amazon error about differing hashed payload values
```

Here is the code for the calculation of the hashed CanonicalRequest string:

```
   public IRestRequest Sign(IRestRequest request, string host)
    {
        DateTime signingDate = AwsSignerHelper.InitializeHeaders(request, host);
        string signedHeaders = AwsSignerHelper.ExtractSignedHeaders(request);

        string hashedCanonicalRequest = CreateCanonicalRequest(request, signedHeaders);

        string stringToSign = AwsSignerHelper.BuildStringToSign(signingDate,
                                                                hashedCanonicalRequest,
                                                                awsCredentials.Region);

        string signature = AwsSignerHelper.CalculateSignature(stringToSign,
                                                              signingDate,
                                                              awsCredentials.SecretKey,
                                                              awsCredentials.Region);

        AwsSignerHelper.AddSignature(request,
                                     awsCredentials.AccessKeyId,
                                     signedHeaders,
                                     signature,
                                     awsCredentials.Region,
                                     signingDate);

        return request;
    }

    private string CreateCanonicalRequest(IRestRequest restRequest, string signedHeaders)
    {
        var canonicalizedRequest = new StringBuilder();
        //Request Method
        canonicalizedRequest.AppendFormat("{0}\n", restRequest.Method);

        //CanonicalURI
        canonicalizedRequest.AppendFormat("{0}\n", AwsSignerHelper.ExtractCanonicalURIParameters(restRequest.Resource));

        //CanonicalQueryString
        canonicalizedRequest.AppendFormat("{0}\n", AwsSignerHelper.ExtractCanonicalQueryString(restRequest));

        //CanonicalHeaders
        canonicalizedRequest.AppendFormat("{0}\n", AwsSignerHelper.ExtractCanonicalHeaders(restRequest));

        //SignedHeaders
        canonicalizedRequest.AppendFormat("{0}\n", signedHeaders);

        // Hash(digest) the payload in the body
        canonicalizedRequest.AppendFormat(AwsSignerHelper.HashRequestBody(restRequest));

        string canonicalRequest = canonicalizedRequest.ToString();

        //Create a digest(hash) of the canonical request
        return Utils.ToHex(Utils.Hash(canonicalRequest));
    }

    //This seems to be the key code - how body is extracted and hashed
    public virtual string HashRequestBody(IRestRequest request)
    {
        Parameter body = request.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(parameter => ParameterType.RequestBody.Equals(parameter.Type));
        string value = body != null ? body.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
        return Utils.ToHex(Utils.Hash(value));
    }
```

So, I am missing and I am not following Amazon convention somewhere, but where. There are multiple points in which something can go bad: 1) maybe `restRequest.AddJsonBody(Serialize(request));` should be doen differently; 2) maybe `HashRequestBody` should be implemented differently (I have found the code somewhere in the Internet or generated by Swagger from Selling Partner API specifications.

How to tweak the code to generate the Hashed payload (for the request with the body) that is exactly the same as calculated by Amazon for the same request (i.e. part of the request that is used for the computation and that is canonicalized before the computing of hashed payload).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve. One should use the code in the question together with these modifications:

It may be important to set TargetApplication:

```
 Model.CreateRestrictedDataTokenRequest request = new Model.CreateRestrictedDataTokenRequest("", restrictedResources);
 request.TargetApplication = "MyApplication";
```

And the different type code should be used for serialization and adding the body. And it is ultimately important to use POST request, not GET request:

```
IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(rdt_resource, Method.POST);
            restRequest.AddParameter("MarketplaceIds", marketplace_id, ParameterType.QueryString);
            String postBody = SerializeBody(request);
            restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", postBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
...
...
    public String SerializeBody(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            return obj != null ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj) : null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

No I am getting the error message:

```
Application does not have access to one or more requested data elements: [buyerInfo, shippingAddress]
```

But it is fine, because technically the registered user and application is recognized and the request and their signatures are well formed.